# Creating share record based on recordId dynamically

Tags: apex, apex-sharing, sharerecord

I am working on a scenario of creating generic apex method of creating share records by using the recordId of an Object. I have a method which accepts recordId, userId, levelOfAccess and sharingReason and trying to create a sharing record after determining the sObjectType.

```
public static Boolean shareRecord(Id recordId, String userId, String levelOfAccess, String sharingReason)
{
    Boolean result = false;
    SObjectType sObjectType;
    String objName;
    if( recordId != null )
    {
        sObjectType = recordId.getSObjectType();
        objName = sObjectType.getDescribe().getName();
        if(!sObjectType.getDescribe().isCustom())
        {
            System.debug('Standard object'+objName);
            String shareObj = objName+share;
            shareObj so = new shareObj();//This line is not working!!
            so.ParentId = recordId;
            so.UserOrGroupId = userId;
            so.objectNameAccessLevel = levelOfAccess;
            so.RowCause = sharingReason;
            insert shareObj;
        }
        else
        {
            System.debug('Custom object'+objName);
            //Insert share record for custom object
        }
    }       
    return result;      
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to construct the share record variable dynamically and trying to insert it. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: P.S. one problem you'll run into is that AccountShare is specially unique, because it defines additional shares besides just the Account (and you can't *not* specify those levels). You may need to create versions that have different parameters or come up with some sort of solution using a Map or other collection type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a String as a type name directly. Instead, you must dynamically resolve the type using `Type.forName()`, and then create a new instance with `newInstance()`:

```
sObject so = (sObject)Type.forName(shareObj).newInstance();
```

Note that since you will not have a concrete sObject instance, you'll have to use the `put()` method to populate fields.

The [`Type`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_type.htm) class is helpful reference documentation.

You have several other syntax errors in this code. The literal string `share` is not quoted correctly, and you do `insert shareObj` instead of `insert so`.